# "arrayFilters" with multilevel query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id": "5cb73f6430d5482becedf21d",
    "terms": [{
        "term": "user",
        "translations": [{
            "history": [],
            "language": "pt",
            "target": "Usuário"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to add sub-documents under terms.translations.history, filtering by the term and by the language fields. I was trying the following update command:

```
let history = {
    action: 'CREATE',
    target: 'Some data....'
};

db.updateOne({
    '_id': id
}, {
    '$push': {
        'terms.$[h].translations.$[i].history': history
    }
}, {
    'arrayFilters': [{
            'h.term': 'user'
        },
        {
            'i.language': 'pt'
        }
    ]
});
```

However, I didn't manage to update the document, when I try to display the raw document using the callback function I get: `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `id` variable ?

Comment: Hi @mickl, _id is an ObjectId.